# Repair broken git history

Tags: git, history

My git history is broken, in the sense that my current branch appears to be 501 commits before my master, which is clearly not the case.

In Intellij Idea I can see that at a certain point there is a jump in my stream, but I did nothing different than branching as usual:

[image]

I had a branch historical_Dev and created a new branch historical_Dev_New. That branch was surprisingly created with the right files (i.e. the last commits on historical_Dev) but wrong history. I didn't realize that immediately and kept committing on historical_Dev_New, and now I need to rebuild history. However rebasing would mean to do a rebasing on all the project source code

What can have occurred? How can I solve it?

Comment: I see you're using a GUI. Can you access a prompt ?

Comment: yes I can , I just used that screenshot to show the problem

Comment: The screenshot doesn't really make the problem very clear - does the first historical_Dev_New commit really not have a parent?

Comment: it looks like, can you help me verifying it?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't pushed these changes to a remote repository, you could use an interactive rebase to clean up your history. More information here: https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase

Comment: Did you push the 501 commits? With an interactive rebase you can remove arbitrary commits in your history back to the last commit you pushed.